# Apps to use for reading local e-books on Windows Surface Pro?

Tags: ebook-readers, windows

Are there any apps available to use for reading local e-books on a Windows Surface pro 4 app? Kindle unfortunately doesn't allow me to do this.

Comment: You should specify which Windows Surface application you want to run this application on. Or do you want to run the application directly on the surface?

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Edge Browser has support for epub built directly into the browser.  Right click and "Open With.." if Edge is not your default browser.  I found it works well with local epub files.  [Edge supports ePub](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/107903/windows-10-tip-read-microsoft-edge)

Answer (score 0):

There are two Kindle apps: the [Windows 10 app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/kindle/9wzdncrfj3vn) and the [desktop app (AKA Kindle for PC)](http://www.amazon.com/kindlepcdownload/ref=klp_win), which you should be able to install on your tablet, if it has an Intel CPU. You should also be able to install any number of epub apps, e.g. [Adobe Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/solutions/ebook/digital-editions/download.html), or browser extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Sumatra will run under Windows 10, is very lightweight and can support both epub and pdf files.